# WebView / webcore error after introducing AdMob

Tags: android, android-webview, admob

I just added an AdView from AdMob into one of my activities. After adding this view, the activity gets started with some noticable lag. In LogCat, I see the following exception. It doesn't cause the app to stop, but shown as a warning:

```
W/webcore(12969): java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
W/webcore(12969):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:2207)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.access$10000(WebViewCore.java:1167)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:2454)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.webkit.WebView.sendOurVisibleRect(WebView.java:3383)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager.setZoomScale(ZoomManager.java:776)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager.access$1900(ZoomManager.java:60)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager$PostScale.run(ZoomManager.java:1372)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5109)
W/webcore(12969):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/webcore(12969):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/webcore(12969):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:991)
W/webcore(12969):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:758)
W/webcore(12969):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/webcore(12969): java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 105) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
W/webcore(12969):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:2207)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.access$10000(WebViewCore.java:1167)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:2454)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.webkit.WebView.sendViewSizeZoom(WebView.java:3619)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager.setZoomScale(ZoomManager.java:782)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager.access$1900(ZoomManager.java:60)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager$PostScale.run(ZoomManager.java:1372)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
W/webcore(12969):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5109)
W/webcore(12969):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/webcore(12969):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/webcore(12969):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:991)
W/webcore(12969):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:758)
W/webcore(12969):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I also noticed that this happens only at the first time the app runs. When I close the app and start again, it doesn't repeat. But the initial run is very important for the user experience so I think it's still an important issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly to do with WebView (used by AdView) creating it internal database, which it only does the first time a WebView is used in your app.

It used to be especially noticeable on Gingerbread (Android 2.3).

To mitigate I would programatically create a WebView when my app first started while showing a splash screen. Make sure you create it on the UI thread (use a handler etc).

Something like (in Activity#onCreate):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  void run() {
    new WebView(MyActivity.this);
  }
});
```

Comment: please explain more this

Comment: In the onCeate of your main activity, programtically create a WebView using a Handler (so that it is async but still on the UI thread). This will cause initialise the global WebView database to be initialised so that subsequenet uses of WebView such as within an AdView do not block for a long time.

Comment: can u provide me code, it very disturb me and it also effects on mobile's processing